# Can't run jax-rs app on docker with tomcat

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, jax-rs

I am new to Java development and was working on a jax-rs app to create restful webservice. My app runs fine on a locally install tomcat server and I can build and run perfectly.

I wanted to dockerize the app for development use and can't seem to figure out how this works. I've worked a little with docker before on a LAMP stack and have had not issues creating a dev environment but just can't get my app to work.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.43-jre8
ADD "C:\\Users\\My Directory\\Documents\\Projects\\npmanager\\target" /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD chmod +x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Run the following:

```
docker build -t mytomcat .
docker run -d -p 8888:8080 --name tomcat_cont mytomcat
```

I can see tomcat come up on the when I go to the local route for docker buy my app still doesn't work.

I tried to ssh into the docker container and realized /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ didn't have my local files.

Here is what my jax-rs app looks like: (not using docker-compose yet)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ADD` is relative to the directory of the build.  It looks like when you run `docker build [...] .` you're within `npmanager Maven Webapp` directory, so you should be able to add the path relative to `.`:

```
ADD target/ /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```